# Razor syntax in c# code block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to populate table data with:

```
        @foreach (var mc in Model.McList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @(@mc.Amount != null ? @mc.Amount @@ @mc.Price : null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

but stuck in razor syntax errors:

> expect :
>
> expect )
>
> or ambiguous invocation: void Write

Amount is int? nullable type.

```
@(@mc.Amount != null ? @mc.Amount : null) //works only with one property
@if (@mc.Amount != null) {@mc.Amount <text>@@</text> @mc.Price} //works
@if (@mc.Amount != null) {@mc.Amount @@ @mc.Price} //error
@if (@mc.Amount != null) {@mc.Amount @:@@ @mc.Price} //error
```

is it shorter way to check for null value without if?

Comment: what are the specific errors? I'd say d.Price is not int (decimal)

Comment: Of course Price is decimal. And i want to achieve similar output: e.g. `120 @ 30.50`

Comment: Would HTML.Raw() help here?

Comment: Does this work? @(mc.Amount != null ? mc.Amount.ToString() + Html.Raw("@") + mc.Price.ToString() : "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to make something that looks like this:

> 5 @ 20

If so, you need to keep in mind that everything between `@(` and `)` is pure C# code; what you need to do is something like this:

```
@(mc.Amount != null ? string.Format("{0} @ {1}", mc.Amount, mc.Price) : "")
```

Comment: Tnx, for opening my eyes. Now i get it better - @ usage in razor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. If you *must* do that in one line, the closest I get is:

```
@(@mc.Amount != null ? string.Format("{0} @ {1}", mc.Amount, mc.Price) : null)
```

I'd probably never do that myself!

Comment: So looks like IF operator is only option there!?

Comment: Don't know, but what's wrong with an IF operator? Is't the construct <exp> ? <exp> : <exp> just syntactic sugar for an if/else? And besides, its not like we can live without IF statements :)

Comment: For me no problem with IF, just looking for shortened code :) As i use that construct in c# often.